# Clojure: how to know if a function (test-vars) printed something to *out*?

Tags: clojure

I am looking for a way to determine if a function printed (using `println` or anything similar).

What I am trying to determine is if `test-vars` printed something or not.

The issue with this function is that it doesn't return anything, but only print things when errors got issues, but I want to know if it succeeded or not and the only way I see to know it is to check if it printed something or not.

Even better would be a way to "intercept" what is going to *out* and to put it in a variable.

After the comments from @lee and @leetwinski I tried the following:

```
(deftest test-1
  (testing
  (is (= 1 2))))
```

Then I tried to run that test using:

```
(let [printed (with-out-str (test-vars [#'test-1]))]
    (print (str "Printed size: " (count printed))))
```

But here is what I got:

```
FAIL in (test-1) (form-init505699766276988020.clj:103)
expected: (= 1 2)
  actual: (not (= 1 2))
Printed size: 0
nil
```

So, what `test-vars` outputs has been outputted anyway. Then `printed` was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to @Lee's answer: in general you could just rebind `*out*` to any other writer you want:

temporary binding:

```
user> (binding [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
        (println 101)
        (str *out*))
"101\n"
```

is just an analogue to `with-out-str`

thread-local binding:

```
user> (set! *out* (java.io.StringWriter.))
#object[java.io.StringWriter 0x575e6773 ""]

user> (println 123)
nil

user> (str *out*)
"123\n"
```

here we rebind the `*out*`, for the current thread (and for all the threads, spawned from it, AFAIK).

Comment: Great thanks @leetwinski & @lee, not sure why I didn't thought about `with-out-str`. It works, but not with `test-vars`. I am looking at the `clojure.test` code and I am not sure why. I think it has something to do with `*test-out*` but I am not sure what. Any ideas?

Comment: You had it almost right, instead of `*out*` it should have been `*test-out*` which is a different one used by tests. Otherwise, the method was exactly the one to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`with-out-str`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-out-str) which intercepts printed values and collects them into a string:

```
(let [printed (with-out-str (test-vars))]
    ...)
```